# spaces in SQL entries

Tags: sql, database

Is it bad practice to have spaces in between words in SQL entries?

**Food Table**

```
id  name         descriptions
--  -----------  ------------
1   large pizza  very large
```

or do you need underscores?

Comment: So... if you're creating a database of old books and their full content, you'd use `_` instead of spaces? `To_be_or_not_to_be,_that_is_the_question` doesn't look quite as nice and readable...

Answer (score 6):

Data is data. Your RDBMS won't care about spaces in the values in its string/text/varchar columns.

Comment: Steve - Text is a type of data. If it makes more sense to you, feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no real difference. Maybe some more typing when entering queries in remembering to place block quotes around field names (i.e. `[your long fieldname]`).

Comment: I think the question was about the data not the field names

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in the records aren't a concern at all.  Quite the opposite.  Adding underscores would only mean that the developer would have to replace them in code. (grumble)

Spaces in the column names can add extra overhead and grumbling for the developer accessing the data.  (For example, in SQL Server, you need to enclose them in square brackets in sql statements.)

Comment: so for field names (column names), one should always use the underscore?

Comment: It depends on the naming convention in your company, but your business will likely have their own standard to ensure consistency.  If you're on your own it's up to you.  I prefer CamelCase to for field names.  (FirstName, LastName)  instead of underscores (First_Name, Last_Name)

Comment: Ok, and on the topic of naming conventions for fields names, if I have a Dog's table, should my field names be DogName | DogColor | DogCollar | Dog'sFavoriteFood etc.... or can it just be name | color | collar | FavoriteFood